# TNS listener does not correctly know of the SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, database-connection

I went through the posts that suggested solutions to the same error but could not fix. I am on windows 8 and on tryign to runa  java program that connects to oracle database by Type 4 driver, I am getting this error:
[image: On running java program]

**On running, lsnrctl status**
[image: Isnrctl status command result]

**and this is inside my listener.ora**

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HP)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

**String that I used to connect to it in my java program is as follows:**

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try changing "@localhost" in the connection string to "@HP". Assuming localhost is 127.0.0.1 and HP is something else.

Comment: It is really funny that it works now because your listener on host HP does not display  an XE instance. Congratulations.

Comment: actually I had to change XE to orcl as well :)and worked with Hp as well as localhost :)